# Fatal ERROR in Moodle "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted..."

Tags: php, sql

I am building a block which needs to execute this SQL statement:

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.fullname AS CourseName, from_unixtime(l.time) AS DateandTime, u.username AS Username,
       l.ip AS IPAddress, u.firstname AS FirstName, u.lastname AS LastName, u.email AS Email, l.module As Activity,
       l.action As Action, l.url As URL, l.info AS Information, r.roleid AS RoleID, l.userid AS UserID, c.id as CourseID
       FROM {log} l, {user} u, {role_assignments} r, {course} c
       WHERE r.userid = l.userid AND c.id = ' . $courseid;
if($Flag == 0)
{
$sql = $sql . " ORDER BY DateandTime Desc";
}
elseif($Flag == 1)
{
$sql = $sql . " ORDER BY Username Asc";
}
```

Where "$courseid" is the selected course ID. when executed, Moodle is returning this ERROR message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2048 bytes) in D:\Moodle\lib\weblib.php on line 1277
```

I did use this php command:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Now after modifying the SQL statement, I am getting this ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 925 bytes) in D:\Moodle\lib\dml\moodle_database.php on line 842
```

And when refreshing the page, I will get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 528 bytes) in D:\Moodle\lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 1022
```

But I know that this is not a solution.

Could anyone help me in this and I will be appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Ahmed

Comment: Those are tiny allocations, so I think your real problem is elsewhere (something is using all the available memory on the machine)

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your reply; The total records are generated from this SQL statement are 21559, as I tried it on MySQL Workbench. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Process the records line by line, and don't store them in memory in the same time.

Comment: Moodle is massive and inefficient.  You're going to need to give PHP more than 128MB to work with.  Change this in php.ini, don't use `ini_set()`.

Comment: Hi Brad, regarding the php.ini, where should I edit it? Also, moodle is hosted by the college servers, and I don't have access to the php.ini. Thanks. Ahmed

Comment: Put an explicit limit with `ini_set()`, then check that you have the correct permission to do that by reading the properties using `ini_get()`. If you can't change this option, ask to your college administrator to increase `memory_limit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moodle provides a method `raise_memory_limit($newlimit);`
The function is declared in setuplib.php and is available as long as config.php is included.

Using this method is the preferred way of raising memory limit in Moodle.

Use it as follows:

`raise_memory_limit([MEMORY_STANDARD|MEMORY_EXTRA|MEMORY_HUGE|MEMORY_UNLIMITED|'128M'|...]);`